# Splitting a 200 bit hexadecimal bitmask

Tags: c#, hex, bitmask

I have a bitmask of 200 bit stored as a hexadecimal value. 
In order to apply the & bit operator, I have to first convert the hex to an integer but 200 bit is too big for a uint64 so my question is : how do I split my bitmask in 4 different hexadecimal value without loosing data?

So that I can also split my 200 bit data and then compare every chunk of data with the corresponding chunk of bitmask without altering the result.

Comment: What is the data type of the stored 200-bit value?

Comment: I do not mean the format, I mean the C# data type (C# does not have a "hexadecimal" data type).

Comment: What is "Hexadecimal"? `byte[]`?

Comment: Oops sorry I am reading the data and bitmask from files so it's in a string

Comment: Then the first step will be to convert the input string to an array of integers (byte/short/int/long), then you will need to perform an bitwise AND operation for all entries in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger) from *System.Numerics* (it's a separate assembly):

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse("01ABC000000000000000000000000000000000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

VERY IMPORTANT: prepend a "0" before the hex number! (because `BigInteger.Parse("F", NumberStyles.HexNumber) == -1`, while `BigInteger.Parse("0F", NumberStyles.HexNumber) == 15`

`BigInteger` implement the "classical" logical operators (`&`, `|`, `^`)

Requires .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of achieving this is writing a class that can store and do binary operations on 200bits of data, have strings as input, etc.